# oracle sql Find max avg of three attempts

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hey need help with finding maximum average weight of three columnes (attempt1, attempt2 and attempt3 and showing which exercise they belong to and what date they occurred.

Atm, the results of the below query outputs, all exercises, all dates they occurred on and all the avg weights. I want it to select the max avg weight, the exercise it belongs to and date it occurred. Attached is the result of the query and ive highlighted what I want to be the output. 
[Result of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0BkV.png)

```
 SELECT e.exercise_description
 , occ.occ_date, (COALESCE(OE.ATTEMPT1, 0)
 + COALESCE(OE.ATTEMPT2, 0)
  + COALESCE(OE.ATTEMPT3, 0))
   /(3 -(COALESCE(OE.ATTEMPT1 - OE.ATTEMPT1, 1)
    + COALESCE(OE.ATTEMPT2 - OE.ATTEMPT2, 1)
     + COALESCE(OE.ATTEMPT3 - OE.ATTEMPT3, 1))
  ) AS row_avg
   FROM EXERCISE E INNER JOIN Occurrence_Exercise OE
  ON E.EXERCISEID=OE.EXERCISEID
    INNER JOIN OCCURRENCE OCC ON OE.OCCURRENCEID=OCC.OCCURRENCEID;
```

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag.  You should show sample data or at least give background as to how you arrived at your current query.

Comment: Surely `OE.ATTEMPT1 - OE.ATTEMPT1` is always going to be zero, or null? Are you supposed to be counting those rather than subtracting them, as part of an average calculation? It's hard to tell what this is supposed to be doing.

Comment: i have three columns, attempt1, attempt2 and attempt3. i want the MAX (avg) of those three columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use window row_number() function to get the biggest avg one

```
SELECT e.exercise_description
     , occ.occ_date
  FROM 
      (SELECT oe.exerciseid
            , oe.occurrenceid
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (COALESCE(oe.attempt1, 0) + COALESCE(oe.attempt2, 0)+ COALESCE(oe.attempt3, 0))
                                          / (NVL2(oe.attempt1, 1, 0) + NVL2(oe.attempt2, 1, 0) + NVL2(oe.attempt3, 1, 0))
                               ) AS rn
       FROM Occurrence_Exercise oe 
      ) srt
 INNER JOIN exercise e 
    ON srt.exerciseid=e.exerciseid
 INNER JOIN occurrence occ 
    ON srt.occurrenceid=occ.occurrenceid
 WHERE srt.rn = 1
```

Comment: Hey your on the right track but that query dosn't output correct results. I'v updated the question for clear understanding.